# How to draw a line inside the form to connect two objects in vb6

Tags: vb6

I am making a flowchart program. I did all of them, but I faced to this problem.
How to draw a line( a connection line) dynamically between two buttons in visual basic through getting a position of a mouse!!

So here's the code of it. I did how to get a position of a cursor, but i cant move forward.

```
Option Explicit 

Private Type POINTAPI
    x As Long 
    y As Long 
End Type 

Private Declare Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" _
    (lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long 

Dim z As POINTAPI 

Private Sub Form_Load() 
    Timer1.Interval = 1 
    Timer1.Enabled = True 
End Sub 

Private Sub Timer1_Timer() 
    GetCursorPos z 
    Label1 = "x: " & z.x 
    Label2 = "y: " & z.y 
End Sub
```

Please help me guys  to fix this problem!! 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need the position of the mouse?

have a look at the following test project:

```
'1 form with:
'  2 command buttons: name=Command1  name=Command2
Option Explicit

Private Sub ConnectButtons(cmd1 As CommandButton, cmd2 As CommandButton)
  Dim sngX1 As Single, sngX2 As Single
  Dim sngY1 As Single, sngY2 As Single
  With cmd1
    sngX1 = .Left + .Width
    sngY1 = .Top + .Height / 2
  End With 'cmd1
  With cmd2
    sngX2 = .Left
    sngY2 = .Top + .Height / 2
  End With 'cmd2
  Line (sngX1, sngY1)-(sngX2, sngY2)
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Click()
  ConnectButtons Command1, Command2
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Resize()
  Command1.Move 120, 120
  Command2.Move ScaleWidth / 2, ScaleHeight / 2
End Sub
```

When you run it, it will show 2 command buttons on a form, when you click on the form it will draw the connecting line

Resize the form to change the position of Command2 and click the form again

Pay attention to the order of Command buttons you pass to the ConnectButtons sub